# Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier ' ' in

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I don't understand what is wrong, how can I have this error for this simple regex.
I can type whatever I want, it will always give me the same error. And in the message itself it doesn't show which modifier causes the problem, the modifier is just empty.

```
public function getRows($content) {
    $regex = '/[a-z]+/';
    preg_match($content, $regex, $rows);
    print_r($rows); exit;
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the order of the parameters. `$regex` goes first, then `$content`.

Comment: yes just noticed ... I need another coffee :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *first* parameter is the regex, the *second* is the subject:

> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject ...

<sup>from [preg_match() in the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)</sup>

So this should work fine:

```
preg_match($regex, $content, $rows);
```

Comment: thanks, very stupid error of me :)